# Invalid partition table

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2

Before getting this "invalid partition table!" warning, I successfully installed Debian and Ubuntu side by side. No problem, no boot warning, no mess with grub, everything ok. But yesterday I decided to downsize my Debian partition (/dev/sda1) in order to make some free space for a new one.

I used Gparted for this job and at first glance everything was fine, except this "invalid partition table!" warning right before the grub screen. Moreover I noticed a warning in the output of `fdisk` which tells that partition 4 has a problem, but I can't see this partition in GParted.

I'm looking for some clarifications about the meaning of this warning. I've found nothing that fits with my problem on the web. I'm stuck and confused currently, after several hours of searching, I feel like I didn't learn anything more...

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cannot see the "invalid partition table" error....

Comment: @MariusMatutiae It happens just before grub. I should take a picture with a camera maybe... x-D Ok, seriously, it's easy to explain: (1) Computer starts. (2) A black screen says: "Invalid partition table!". (3) I press Enter to access Grub. That's it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I used to see this at work, with certain disk images being put into production (basically, dd an image over to a disk). I had this explained to me, and if I remember correctly, it's a warning, not an errer. It's a remnant from the bronze age when partitions had to start at sector boundaries, which they don't anymore. Some OSes may not like it, but unless you're having severe problems during boot, then you need not worry.

Looking at your fdisk output I see nothing alarming except from the warning itself.

Comment: Thx Jarmund :-) Actually I'm looking for some clarification about the meaning of this "Invalid partition table!" warning. Moreover, I'd like to remove it if possible :-|